# msbuild hangs after building xamarin.forms ios project with syntax error

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild

I'm trying to build Xamarin.Forms iOS application from bat file, on windows machine. It works fine if there is no syntax errors in builded project. But if there is some syntax error, that prevents project from building, then msbuilds hangs after finishing build (see attached picture).

I've tested this on five different machines and it behaves like this on three of them, but on two works perfectly fine (msbuild finishes it's work, and returns control to cmd).

I'm attaching sample project (Xamarin.Forms template with a syntax error in Main.cs), steps to reproduce this problem:

1. go to *Clean.iOS* directory
2. edit *runc.bat* - set *ServerAddress*, *ServerUser* and *ServerPassword*, possibly change path to msbuild also.
3. open cmd (or windows terminal)
4. run *runc.bat* and wait till it finishes.

On some machines it will end and returns control to *cmd* but on some it will hang after displaying error messages and build time.

Additional information:

- Visual Studio: 16.8.2
- Xamarin.Forms: 4.8.0.1451
- system: Windows 10, Version 2004
- msbuild: 16.8.2.56705

Link to sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mm8rC_D2zpCZZaKYRuX53oBIMDRoq4AD/view?usp=sharing
[image]